# How do i calculate the value of character,number and symbols in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

### i know that:

```
ord(chr(21)) is 21
ord('d') is 100
ord('#') is 35
```

However, i have a variable that has characters, numbers,symbols and i need to calculate the sum!!

Comment: Can you show us the variable that has your "characters, numbers, and symbols"? Have you made any attempts to calculate the values of your "characters, numbers, and symbols" or sum them up?

Answer (score 0):

Then use `sum` along with `map` to map `ord` to the characters:

```
w = '1#adr3$$!'

sum(map(ord, w))
551
```

Which is equivalent to providing a comprehension to `sum`:

```
sum(ord(i) for i in w)
```

which takes the `ord` of every character in `w` and sums it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to compare characters inside 2 different strings. for instance:  A B C D E  and E D S D S. how can i compare the first 2 character of two strings and randomly move one step, then do that to the 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... character?